# Microsoft teams app: How to maintain versioning of backend services

Tags: microsoft-teams, versioning

We have developed a app for Microsoft teams and our first version was published on the app store. We are now working on the next version. However we are not sure how we have to submit the new version for team store review without impacting the existing users. For instance, some of our bot commands will behave differently in the new version. If we have only one backend instance running, when we submit it to store team for review we will impact the experience of existing production users as well.

Ideally we would follow a blue-green approach to release new features to selected customers, but in this case we are not really sure how and where to differentiate requests coming (mainly through bot communication, since we can add a app version header in web communication) from multiple versions of the app.   We thought of creating new set of resources (app registration, bot channel registration etc) on Azure portal but I guess that would be treated as a new app and not a version update.

Any ideas or pointers on how to achieve this would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good point, I don't think there's anything out of the box to deal with this. What you've suggested might indeed be the best way:

1. create new app registration & bot channel registration, with temporary name (e.g. MyBot2)
2. update manifest to use new bot, and submit for store approval with this manifest
3. once approved, and app is live (you can schedule a go-live time when you submit the app), rename both bots (original to MyBotV1 or something, and MyBot2 to MyBot)

In any case, I'd work with the app submission team around this, they're very helpful and engaged.